# How to install Vagrant with manual VirtualBox 4.2?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

How can I install Vagrant 1.0.6. with an already manually installed VirtualBox 4.2.6 on Ubuntu 12.04? All of my known ways fail:

1. Download *.deb file for 64bit and `dpkg --install vagrant_x86_64.deb` gives me the error `Vagrant not installed. Use apt-get install vagrant` after using `vagrant up`.
2. Using `apt-get install vagrant` wants to remove (!) my manual VirtualBox installation.

What to do?

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
apt-get install vagrant --no-install-recommends
```

as a work-around.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vagrant/+bug/1125097

Answer (score 3):

Find you installed vagrant in /opt/vagrant and create a symlink on you local bin.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant /usr/local/bin/vagrant
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Up to 1.0.7** the recommended way of installing `vagrant` is through RubyGems.

Update: now that someone down voted the answer, I realized that it should be updated anyway.

**NOTE: Since Vagrant 1.1.x (now 1.2.4) the recommended way of installation is using the install package (DEB, RPM) for Linux, DMG for OS X and MSI Windows.**

If you have up-to-date ruby version installed, just `gem install vagrant`.

You can install ruby using package management, of course. However, [rbenv/ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is highly recommended, it's more flexible and works great in terms of managing ruby versions.

Update: since 1.2, recommended way of installing Vagrant is using the installers for your OS.

Comment: Currently the vagrant documentation says,"But note that the packages [not the ruby gem] are the preferred and best supported method of installation." The answer about the symbolic link worked for me. P.S. Agree, however, about RVM in generally and specifically if using the vagrant gem.

Comment: Cool. Good to see it worked fine for you. I actually never tried to install the vagrant .deb package as I already have Ruby;-)